# Zend Framework-2: Best way to protect all Controllers? (ZfcUser/HybridAuth)

Tags: zend-framework2, hybridauth, zfcuser

I am using `ZfcUser` via `HybridAuth` for enabling Facebook Authentication in `Zend` `Framework 2`. I downloaded the `scn-social-auth` module and added into my project. Now, the Controller `user` under `ZfcUser` module is protected. That is, if I am not logged in, it will redirect me to the login page.

User not logged in: visit "http://localhost/user" => will redirect to: "http://localhost/user/login"

Now, I want to protect all my Controller Actions with `ZfcUser`. That is, any module I create, if I the user is not logged in, it should redirect me to "http://localhost/user/login". What is the best of doing this? I can check whether the user is logged in each of the action in each module. But, it doesn't look like a good option. Any suggestion?

Regards,
Shiva

Comment: Implement https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize

Answer (score 3):

Some code that may be useful is included in an issue for ZfcUser: https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/issues/187, which provides a clean and neat solution for this trouble.

Hope this helps :-)